# Is the new HP printer vulnerability only relevant for network printers?

Tags: printers

[There is a new vulnerability announced for HP M553 printers](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/21/patch_coming_for_hp_printer_vulnerabilities/). On my reading, however, it appears that it only affects network printers. In other words if two people are connected to the same printer, one person might be able to see the other person's print jobs.

I have an M553 but it is only connected to one PC via a USB cable. Does that mean the vulnerability is irrelevant for me?

Answer (score 2):

As it seems there are a few bugs causing a remote code execution vulnerability. That kind of vulnerability would be able for your printer, because your printer is connected to your computer which is connected to a internet connection. I would recommand you to install the patches they'll release next week, cause they fix some other bugs, too. Don't be worry, I guess you have a antivirus software running on your computer, so the vulnerability is unlikely to bother you.